# Is there a way to replace a character in one column of a dataframe with a character from a second column based on a character in a third column?

Tags: r

This is an example of my current df:

```
region         subsector        market
AK              biomass          USA
AK            electricity        USA
AK               coal        Alaska grid
KS              biomass          USA
KS               coal        Kansas grid
```

If subsector = biomass, I need to replace the market for that row with the region from that row.  The df is 15,000+ entries, so I need it to be automated. Note: Each region will have more than one biomass subsector. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a logical vector by checking if the 'subsector' value is 'biomass', use that to extract the values from 'region' and assign it to the corresponding 'market'

```
i1 <- df$subsector == 'biomass'
df$market[i1] <- df$region[i1]
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the columns are all `character`. If it is `factor`, one option is `type.convert`

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Or using `as.character`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse` :

```
df$market <- with(df, ifelse(subsector == 'biomass', region, market))
```